# Is there something similiar to JSTL library for Ant build script

Tags: java, ant

I am now required to maintain some Ant build scripts and I am new to it. I want to lookup the description and use case of some tags like `<propertyregex>` but I fail to find any tag library for Ant.

Where can I find the tag library for Ant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a taglib as such. It's a Java tool. You should be able to find documentation on ANT [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) and some additional [tasks here](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html)

From the second link, this is the definition for `propertyregex`

> PropertyRegex: Performs regular expression operations on an input string, and sets the results to a property. There are two different operations that can be performed:
>
> Replacement - The matched regular expression is replaced with a substitition pattern
> Selection - Groupings within the regular expression are selected via a selection expression.